# Yii selecting only specified attributes in array

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I often face this problem..

Lets say ..In blog application, I need to email all the active users..

What I do is write findAll on users with some conditions of their last login being greater than some value..and get all the User objects...Then run a foreach through all the user model objects and store emails in a array, then use the array..

I other words what is happening in back-end is I am loading whole model, while I only need barely`0.5%` of that information, and then running a dirty code to get values in in array, and then process with it..

Isn't it quite bad in performance and dirty code..

Now other approach I can think of is using `commandBuilder` and write query and then run same dirty code to get values in array..one problem of performance resolved..but as people say writing sql in mvc frameworks, is not a really good idea..

What I really want...some similar functions which give me column values in array if it is a single column, or array with column name as index if multiple columns..

So what I am thinkin of doing is implement it by extending ActiveRecord or something similar, **what I want to check is if some one has already implemented something similar, or have some ideas for it..:)**

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes

Comment: Probably he needs to select some fields instead of all fields. Use the CDbCriteria::select to get which fields you need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I created the behavior as I said, the way it works is:

```
$active_users_emails = User::model()->findColumn('email', 'active = 1');

**returns array('rajat@gmail.com','rajatsinghal@gmail.com')..**
```

> Now one doesn't need to go through all activerecords and collect
>   column in array, then proceed, and also bear weight of loading whole
>   column..

You can find the extension on git ..https://github.com/rajatsinghal/CAdvancedArFindBehavior

Answer (score 15):

You must study of CDbCriteria deeply, their is all the things what your looking.

Have an example::

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 't.first_name, t.email'; // select fields which you want in output
$criteria->condition = 't.status = 1';

$data = Users::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

$data is also an array output.

Comment: Please clear your question, i replied on the basis of what i understood.

Comment: why settings  't.first_name' but not 'a.first_name'. I tried 'a.first_name' but it didn't work unlike the first one. Is it some kind of convention?

Comment: Alex, It's a default table alias. Yii creates queries like "SELECT t.id FROM table t", but it may vary depends on query complexity (multiple tables queries). Check http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#getTableAlias-detail

Comment: @Копать_Шо_я_нашел remove alias

Answer (score 14):

In Yii2, you can use like this:

```
User::find()->select(['field1', 'field2']);
```

Comment: This should be the approved answer

Comment: @realtebo Yes this should be the approved answer but Question asking upon yii1 not yii2

Comment: Say you do `$data = User::find()->select(['field1','field2']);`  
and then you print $data->attributes. You'll find all the columns of the table will null values.

Answer (score 6):

This would also work without any behavior or without the addition to CActiveRecord. Nevertheless I also like the solution with the behavior.

```
$active_users_emails=CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('active'=>1)), 'id', 'email');
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to filter the model attributes using **array_filter** function. Try like this, its working great -

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 't.first_name, t.email'; // select fields which you want in output
$criteria->condition = 't.status = 1';

$data = Users::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Use array_filter before assign.

```
foreach($data as $model){
      $rows[] = array_filter($model->attributes);
   }

echo CJSON::encode($rows)
```

So, you will get output like this -

```
[{"first_name" : "Rohit", "email" : "rohitsuthar@gmail.com"}, {"first_name" : "Rajat", "email" : "rajat@example.com"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

In same situation as question describes.
After trying all above answers and some other resources here is what I am doing.

```
$emailIds = Yii::app()->db->createCommand(
                 'SELECT email FROM users WHERE is_active = 1'
            )->queryAll();

$emailIds = array_column( $emailIds, 'email' ) );
```